# blob\text images from MySQL return NULL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, blob

I post few days ago
[Pass MySQL medium blob into IOS NSData\UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010499/pass-mysql-medium-blob-into-ios-nsdata-uiimage)
but didn't manage to find a solution yet. my specific problem is that when I retrieve images from database, blob or text, it returns NULL, rows that don't have variables in them just return blank

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

 $add = array(); 
 $add["Id"] = $row["Id"]; 
 $add["Mail"] = $row["Mail"];
 $add["Category"] = $row["Category"]; 
 $add["Phone"] = $row["Phone"]; 
 $add["Msgs"] = $row["Msgs"];
 //image from blob
 $add["Picture"] = $row["Picture"];

 // push single add into final response array 
 array_push($response["adds"], $add); 
}
```

is there any other way to address images from blob\text?! I tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/6273415/1333294 but nothing works for me.

Comment: Are you sure that Picture field is set in your DB?
Can you provide me schema and data for table, that you use?

Comment: Picture mediumtext utf8_general_ci . all other fields return their values fine

Comment: I think that your field is empty in database. Can you check it?
Do select statement:
`SELECT Picture FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME`
And then post the result

Comment: ‰PNG

IHDR€hHPÝiDOT...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally!!

```
    $img = $row["Picture"];
    $b64img = base64_encode ($img);
    $b64img = mysql_real_escape_string($b64img);
    $add["Picture"] = $b64img;
```

simple as that! and xcode get it as base64 string and nut NULL. thanks for suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

echo $row['picture'];

// Display image with img html tag

echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode( $row['picture'] ) . '" />';

echo 'Hello world.';
```

please find sample code

```
$response["adds"] = array();
$add = array(); 
$add["Id"] = 1; 
$add["Mail"] = "test@mm.com";
$add["Category"] = "category"; 
$add["Phone"] = "1234567"; 
$add["Msgs"] = "ths s txt msg";
//image from blob
$add["Picture"] = "pciture";

// push single add into final response array 
array_push($response["adds"], $add); 
print_r($response["adds"]);
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
print $response["adds"][0]['Picture'];
```

Comment: but im pushing an array array_push($response["adds"], $add) , and all other values are strings...

Comment: nop! still null. but I did manage to pass the data when I converted the rows on my table from medium text to medium blob, apparently the conversion converted the data into text. how can I, inside the php, convert image into string before inserting it into blob?